# SQL Query for Internal Messaging System

Tags: sql-server, mysql, database-design, performance, query-performance

I'm creating an internal messaging system (No SMTP/POP3) and I'm looking for a way to query a user's list of messages. Here's my schema:

`Messages`

```
_MessageID (PK) 
_MessageParentID (if a reply this will equal MessageID) 
_Body
_Date
_CreatorID (FK userID of the message creator)
```

`MessageRecipients`

```
_MessageRecipientID (PK)
_MessageID (FK to message)
_SendTo (FK UserID)
```

In short what I'm doing is creating a one to many relationship for messages. One user can send a message to many recipients. But the replies are one to one, in short message blasts are possible but there are no group conversations.

I created a SQL Fiddle to demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6421e3/7

In the query I have now, I'm close. The User 101 should have 3 rows instead of the 4 showing. `MessageID` 4 is a reply to `MessageID` 3 (MessageParentID = MessageID) so I'm wanting the latest message to display and since the date of `MessageID` 4 is greater it should be displayed in the query. Think how FB Messaging works, you see the latest reply to a thread - not a separate outbox.

E.g. expected output:

3 rows

MessageID 1, 2, 4

Any help would be great.

Comment: what do you mean by combined? Id 3 should be remove or id 4 should have text from both id 3 and 4? Can you edit the question and add the expected output?

Comment: Just made edits, combined was the wrong word. Id 3 should be removed i.e. not present since id 4 is the latest based on date/Id. The expected output will have rows id: 1,2,4

Comment: Why is the question tagged with both `sql-server` and `mysql`? Which one of the two are you using?

Comment: Because I wanted to attract more viewership for the query in question whether its SQLServer or MySQL doesn't matter. Whichever way the query can be created I can translate to fit the environment's needs. But it is in fact for a SQLServer db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use this query ([sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6421e3/11/0)):

```
SELECT [MessageID]
    , [Body]
    , [Date]
    , [MessageParentID] 
FROM Messages 
WHERE MessageID NOT IN (
        SELECT MessageParentID FROM Messages
    )
```

Basicaly, if a MessageID is also a MessageParentID it means there is at least 1 reply. Therefore it only looks for message without replies (ie. without MessageParentID).

With this limited sample, it gives the correct output:

```
MessageID   Body                            Date                        MessageParentID
1           Its getting hot in hure         December, 27 2015 00:00:00  0 
2           Where is all the chicken?       December, 28 2015 00:00:00  0 
4           Sometimes its a little hotter   January, 05 2016 00:00:00   3
```

I don't unsderstand why:

- are you using a GROUP BY with all the columns in SELECT. Do you need a DISTINCT?
- are you using Max(M.Date) and anyway, it is also included in the group by
- you are joining to MessageRecipients since anythin from the recipient list or count are not needed

Comment: Thank your sir! Group BY is needed so that if a message is sent to more than one person it doesn't appear twice in the query. I don't necessarily need the Max(M.Date) you're correct. MessageRecipients is needed as it's my intent to query all Messages sent & received by a user at any given time. Here's an updated version of its intended usage: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6421e3/26. You're solution got me on the correct path thanks again.

Comment: Your GROUP BY is strictly similar to the selected columns with no aggregate. This is not needed and you can replace it by a simple SELECT DISTNCT...